# Change Background Color on IphoneX

Tags: cordova, statusbar, iphone-x

I want to change the color of the space between the home bar and the footer of my application.

[image: Image Footer]

My app is on cordova and I'm just using cordova status bar plugin.
I have already configured a staus bar background color in config.xml (`<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#222222" />`) but that space is not in the body of my app. I just want to change color. Not else.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Sorry , I solved this question. If you have installed this plugin cordova-plugin-webviewcolor, you can use this function window.plugins.webviewcolor.change('#222222'); after deviceready that change the webview color.

Comment: If you solved this, please post your answer as a *proper answer.*